# node.js, append html into a return function

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, express, append

I'm doing a web application with Node.js, Express, Jade and MongoDb.
I've done a page in which users have to put a confirmation code into a form; this call a function that check if the code is right (checkConfirmationCode).

I would like to append an html text like "your code is right/wrong" into the confirmation page.
the function is like this:

```
exports.checkConfirmationCode = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        var sentCode = req.body.confirmationCode;
        var rightCode= '123456';
        if(sentCode==rightCode)
            //append html to the request page
        else
            //append html to the request page
   };
};
```

What's the best way for doing this?
I was thinking about jquery, something like

```
$("#content").append("your code is right/wrong")
```

but it does't work, I should use any jquery npm, is right?
Is this a good way for doing this?

Comment: If you want to do it with no page refresh, you'll need a client side AJAX request -- if a page refresh is fine, just use `res.send("Your code is right")`

Comment: In this way I lose the rest of the page, I see only "Your code is right"

Comment: Yes - it loads a new page. If you want to keep the page you'll need to use an AJAX request

Comment: Ok, and for now if I want to send back an entire page with res.send(A LOT OF HTML CODE) how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

your code is at server side(node.js)
and where you want to put the alert message is client side.

So you have to send the result to the client to let the client display the message somehow.

so,

1.Send things user wrote to the server via Get/Post/socket.io/AJAX or whatever you like

2.check whether the code is correct or not in node.js

3.send the result to the client as http response(body of whole page plus the alert message) or sending the result via socket.io/AJAX asynchronously

(only the case you used socket.io/AJAX)

4.when the client receives the result,append result message to html by jquery.

here is an instance of socket.io

server side

```
var io = require('socket.io');

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('formAnswer',function(data){
        //check whether data.answer is correct answer or not
        if(data.answer = collect){
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit({
                message : 'your code is right'
            });
        }else{
            io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit({
                message : 'your code is wrong'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

client side(template file such as something.ejs)

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('resultData',function(data){
    $("#content").append(data.message);
});
</script>
//send what user wrote when submit is pushed.
<script>
$answerForm.submit(function(e){
    socket.emit('formAnswer',{answer : 'what user wrote'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As `tymeJV` said, the only way to avoid the page reload is by binding the code verification submit button to do an ajax POST to the express endpoint that will return either a 200 if code was correct or 401 (Unauthorized) if code is wrong.

```
exports.checkConfirmationCode = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {
        // presumably DB lookup for rightCode here
        if(req.body.confirmationCode === rightCode) {
            res.send(200);
        } else {
            res.send(401);
        }
    }
}
```

And your express setup should include the `bodyParser` middleware a route for POSTs assuming the endpoint is `/confirmCode`:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);

app.post('/confirmCode', checkConfirmationCode(db));
```